# a virtual Kinect device

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

Like daemon tools, which creates a virtual drive for loading the iso files, is there any way we can run and compile(basically for testing) our kinect programs without the kinect device .I understand that the code would require  the depth and ir sensor of kinect..

Comment: To what end?  You can install the SDK, write and compile Kinect applications without the hardware plugged in.  If you want to run it without the Kinect plugged in, just look to see if it is connected `else` degrade gracefully.

Comment: The purpose is to not have a Kinect connected at all but still test your application. Imagine a team of developers working on a Kinect enabled game; instead of having to buy/use one Kinect per developer you could record one test session and then have the developers run this to test their edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Fakenect from OpenKinect:
http://openkinect.org/wiki/Fakenect

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that is possible. Device is what interacting with the real world. So how are you going to get depth data without the device and check whether your program works..??